# Decoding bytes as unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

The question is how to extract string, which represented as bytes (warning) in string? What I actually mean:

```
>>> s1 = '\\xd0\\xb1'  #  But this is NOT bytes of s1! s1 should be 'б'!
'\\xd0\\xb1'
>>> s1[0]
'\\'
>>> len(s1)            #  The problem is here: I thought I would see (2), but:
8
>>> type(s1)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(s1[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> s1[0] == '\\'
True
```

So how can i convert **s1** to **'б'** (cyrillic symbol - the real representation of **'\xd0\xb1'**). I already asked here a similiar question, but my bad was misunderstood of real represented view of **s1** (i thought that **'\'** was **'\'**, not the **'\\'**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code. Warning, it is only a proof of concept. When the text contains also characters written as non-escape sequences, the replacement must be done the more complicated way (I will show later when wanted). See the comments below.

```
import binascii

s1 = '\\xd0\\xb1'
print('s1 =', repr(s1), '=', list(s1))            # list() to emphasize what are the characters

s2 = s1.replace('\\x', '')
print('s2 =', repr(s2))

b = binascii.unhexlify(s2)
print('b =', repr(b), '=', list(b))

s3 = b.decode('utf8')
print('s3 =', ascii(s3))

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(s3)
```

It prints on concole:

```
c:\__Python\user\so20210201>py a.py
s1 = '\\xd0\\xb1' = ['\\', 'x', 'd', '0', '\\', 'x', 'b', '1']
s2 = 'd0b1'
b = b'\xd0\xb1' = [208, 177]
s3 = '\u0431'
```

And it writes the character to the `output.txt` file.

The problem is that the question combines both unicode escaping and escaping binary values. In other words, the unicode string can contain some sequence that represents binary value somehow; however, you cannot force that binary value into the unicode string directly, because any unicode character is actually an abstract integer, and the integer can be represented in many ways (as a sequence of bytes).

If the unicode string contained escape sequences like `\\n`, it could be done differently, using the 'unicode_escape' prescription for `bytes.decode()`. However, in this case, you need both decoding from ascii escape sequences and then from utf-8.

**Update:** Here is a function for converting your kind of strings with other ascii characters (i.e. not only the escape sequences). The function use the finite automaton -- may look too complex at first (actually it is only verbose).

```
def userDecode(s):
    status = 0
    lst = []                       # result as list of bytes as ints
    xx = None                      # variable for one byte escape conversion
    for c in s:                    # unicode character
        print(status, ' c ==', c)  ## just for debugging
        if status == 0:
            if c == '\\':
                status = 1         # escape sequence for a byte starts
            else:
                lst.append(ord(c)) # convert to integer

        elif status == 1:          # x expected
            assert(c == 'x')
            status = 2

        elif status == 2:          # first nibble expected
            xx = c
            status = 3

        elif status == 3:          # second nibble expected
            xx += c
            lst.append(int(xx, 16)) # this is a hex representation of int
            status = 0

    # Construct the bytes from the ordinal values in the list, and decode
    # it as UTF-8 string.
    return bytes(lst).decode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = userDecode('\\xd0\\xb1whatever')
    print(ascii(s))    # cannot be displayed on console that does not support unicode

    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(s)
```

Look also inside the generated file. Remove the debug print. It displays the following on the console:

```
c:\__Python\user\so20210201>b.py
0  c == \
1  c == x
2  c == d
3  c == 0
0  c == \
1  c == x
2  c == b
3  c == 1
0  c == w
0  c == h
0  c == a
0  c == t
0  c == e
0  c == v
0  c == e
0  c == r
'\u0431whatever'
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Anyway, how did you get the string with the escape sequences?

Comment: There is a Flask server. The message (string) is crypted by RSA key at server-side and returned as binary data ... in string (like s1 in example). It's taken using Requests package on the client-side. Bad news: i have no access to server sources so i can not change the format used to send crypted message.

Update: there is miss of few things:
1. Message crypted by RSA key at server;
2. It is sended to client like binary data in string format (like s1);
3. It is recieved at client and decrypted;
4. The result is something like s1.

Comment: I see. Anyway, isn't it some "well known" (not to me) way of escaping the transfered content? If yes, there could be some module around for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s1 = b'\xd0\xb1' 
>>> s1.decode("utf8")
'б'
>>> len(s1)
2
```

Comment: Why do you put a `b` in there, why not `r` for raw string?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac because it *isn't* a raw string - the backslashes are meaningful. The b makes it a byte string. `\xd0` is a single byte, with the value 0xD0. You can combine them (making it a raw byte string), but then you trigger the same error as the OP.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I did not know that these were byte-strings. Much appreciated :) Come to the python chatroom sometimes, I'm sure we could all learn a lot from you :)

Comment: It could be a solution for problem, but s1 theoretically may be declared in side-code (other sources, came from internet, et cetera). The question is not how to convert '\xd0\xb1' with len == 2 to 'б', but how to convert '\\xd0\\xb1' with len == 8 to 'б'